# Homework solution x columns

Tags: rules, multicol, columns

I'm writing a book and in its end, I write the exercises solutions. To become with a better layout, I use `multicols` environment, like this:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item answer 1
    \item answer 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

But, when an exercise have two or more items, like 1a) 1b) and I write these solutions in another `multicols` environment, the vertical line extends to it. I tried to use `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.0pt}` to fix it, but when I do, it erases the vertical line.

I get something like this:

```
1.          # 6. 
2a)  | b)   # 7.
 c)  | d)   # 8.
3.          # 9.
4.          # 10.
5.          # 11.
```

where `#` means the main vertical line (that I want to keep) and `|` means the vertical line of an exercise (that I tried to erase using `0.0pt`).

I hope you understand my problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please turn your code fragment into a complete compilable document that shows exactly the problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional argument after the number of columns to specify code to be executed before the environment. Here is a minimal example (like the one you it would have been helpful to put into your question.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item answer 1
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
    \item Barr
    \item Foo
    \item bar
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \item answer 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

You can use local values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item answer 1
{% here (P.S)
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item answer 1
    \item answer 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}}
    \item answer 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have an extra `\setlength` in your code (the one inside the second `multicols` environment.)  This solution also isn't as semantically transparent as using the extra argument that the `multicols` environment provides.

Comment: @AlanMunn Removed. Thank you! I prefer using local arguments, hovewer in this case your solution is easier to use, of course.